# Is there a way to do a "INSERT INTO with auto_increment if not exists"?

Tags: mysql, auto-increment, insert-into

I have a table that looks like this:

```
| ID | int PRIMARY  
| Name | varchar  
| timestamp | timestamp
```

How do I do this knowing an ID?

To show you better what I want, here's an example using two queries to help you understand better:

1st I just do a SELECT query to see if the ID exists.
if it does not exist (the most common), I create a new row ignoring the ID I was given as input and I use MySQL's AUTO_INCREMENT for the ID.

Is there a way to archive this?

**Note:** Due to how foreign keys work here. using the REPLACE instead of INSERT INTO is **not** an answer.

**Note2:** Because I want to force the use of the AUTO_INCREMENT if it does not exist, at first glance, the INSERT IGNORE INTO also does not seem to be the answer. Unless I'm missing something... That's also why I'm asking.

Comment: So if ID 5 does not exist, you want to `INSERT` with an auto-incremented ID instead? This doesn't make any sense. Why are you doing this?

Comment: @tadman Because the id is obtained from the user. I don't want the user to decide the ID's when it is created! I'm the one who decides! Got the idea ;)?

Comment: It sounds like you're creating an ORM. Usually this ends badly. Why don't you use a pre-existing one?

Comment: @tadman It's not an ORM, hopefully. At least, that's not the intent.

Comment: Doing direct database manipulation is probably a bad idea. Are you sure you want to go down this road?

Comment: @tadman Yes. I don't like using frameworks and such. The controls of the database are almost too high level to my taste but it's still comfortable for me. With frameworks, then it becomes too uncomfortable. It's something I can't really explain.

Comment: I think you will need to use another table as an auto_increment counter to achieve this.

Comment: hum... I get the picture. Ok thanks for the help. I'll use the extra table strategy

Comment: If you're uncomfortable with frameworks, you're using the wrong frameworks. You'll be at least an order of magnitude more productive with the right framework than without one. Hammering out queries by hand is hard, and should be the exception to what you're doing, not the rule. For example, what you're doing here is like three lines of code in a REST-ful application.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are looking to do is update on duplicate key

```
INSERT INTO yourTable (
    id,
    name,
    timestamp
) VALUES (
    5,
    'something',
    NOW()
)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    name = VALUES(name),
    timestamp = VALUES(timestamp);
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

The `INSERT () VALUES ()` is straight forward.  `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` tells it that if a UNIQUE / PRIMARY key conflicts, then this should instead update some values within that row.  The `fields = VALUES(fields)` syntax tells it to update those fields within the conflicting row with the values as specified within the INSERT.

The second approach would be to use a stored procedure to handle INSERTs to your table which does the prerequisite SELECT, as you cannot both SELECT and INSERT on a table in the same query.

Comment: Which bit of this inserts with an auto-incremented `id`?

Comment: It would just insert with the specified id.  To get it to insert with AI you need to modify the id column value to be NULL if it doesn't exist.  I'll have a play on SQL fiddle and see if I can come up with something

Comment: "It would just insert with the specified id. To get it to insert with AI you need to modify the id column value to be NULL" read the question. You are answering a question I didn't make. You are answering the question I have without the condition I wrote about having to use the A_I if inserting